# what is Minimum Viable Pod (MVP)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

What is Minimum Viable Pod (MVP) in kubernetes?

i've tried to google it but nothing useful was there...

i've heard about the MVP consept when i saw [this](https://github.com/BretFisher/kubernetes-mastery/blob/f81ab571d61bef2b4d383f121d6c394a217d4176/k8s/nginx-1-without-volume.yaml) yaml file and couldn't get what is MVP and why this pod is a MVP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest possible manifest that you need to write in order to run a pod.